# GPIO toggle for 5 seconds while booting kernel

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I want to toggle a gpio for 5s for enabling a modem while booting itself
Currently i use a script

```
echo 10 > /sys/class/gpio/export

echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction

echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value

echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value

sleep 5

echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value
```

**I know this causes the booting process to halt for 5s ,**

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last two lines by

```
sleep 5; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/value &
```

That makes the command list of `sleep` and `echo` in the background.